# joins query with many-to-many rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to check if a user is a member of event. But getting this error.

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, through: :memberships

    def has_membership?(user)
        joins(:memberships).where(memberships: { user_id: user.id })
    end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :events, through: :memberships
end
```

EventsController

```
    def show
        @event = Event.find_by_id(params[:id])
        if @event.has_membership?(current_user)
            render json: @event, status: 200 
        else
            render json: {
                error: "Permission denied"
            }, status: 422
        end
    end
```

Returns:

```
undefined method `joins' for <Event:0x000000059a3148>
```

But if I try in irb: `Event.joins(:memberships).where(memberships: { user_id: user.id })` it shows correct data.

Comment: Why do you need to join? Can't you query the `Membership` directly. `Membership.where(user_id: user.id, event_id: self.id)`

Comment: Thank you! It is better solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because `has_membership?` is working on a single instance of `Event` but `joins` is a class method of `Event`.

You could work around that by doing

```
def has_membership?(user)
  Event.joins(:memberships)
    .where(id: self.id)
    .where(memberships: { user_id: user.id })
end
```

But in this instance a better way would be to avoid joining alltogether and query the `Membership` directly

```
Membership.where(user_id: user.id, event_id: self.id)
```